# Updating Like Button Without Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a Like button. It's working fine. After Like button completes it's functionality I'm trying to update the button text (Like to Liked) without refreshing the page, but problem is that It's updating the every single Like button on the webpage (until I refresh the page) not just the one I clicked on . . .

Here's that success function in AJAX call,

```
$('.like-click').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var this_ = $(this);
var quesURL = this_.attr('like-href');
$.ajax({
    url: quesURL,
    method: 'GET',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        var like_text = $(data).find('.like-click').html();
        $('.like-click').html(like_text);
    }
})
});
```

Here's the HTML code,

```
{% for data in datas %}
     ...
     <a class="like-click" like-href="...">{% if user in Likes %}Liked{% else %}Like{% endif %}</a>
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

How can I update the button I clicked, not all of them ?

Answer (score 1):

You have saved your clicked element in var this_, so you have to just update that element text only via replacing $('.like-click').html(like_text); to $(this_).html(like_text);

So it will not update each button text.

Comment: Have my code works for you? It will update only clicked element because j-query understand that it via this_ variable.

Comment: Yes, Sir code is working fine :) But why it's working for the first element only?

Comment: It will not update first element but will update text of current clicked element.

Comment: Sir, this code is showing a different behavior. If I like First button only then It's updating rest of the buttons (if I click them). And If First button is not Liked then It's not updating if I click rest of the buttons first. Why so?

Comment: I think you are still doing something wrong can I get your complete requirement, if button clicks for like then it will updated with liked and user can't clicked on that right?

Comment: Can you create one demo so I will update your code in that.

Comment: Sir, back end is working perfectly fine. Problem is that, If `First` element is Liked & I Like second or third element it's fine BUT if `First` element is not liked and I like second or third element then it's not updating it to Liked. Why so?

Comment: What you are returning in your response of data variable?

Comment: `data` variable is returning the raw html code of entire webpage.

Comment: I think you just have to update a tag href and text of a tag so just add code in your success that $(this_).text("Liked"); and $(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(0);"); OR $(this).attr("href",UNLIKE_URL);

Comment: Sir, it's still causing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Why you use AJAX for this? You are not pulling "Like" or "Liked" from database. Do it with simple handler:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(
       function(){
         $(".button div").toggle();
       }
    )
});


<button type="button" class="button like-click">
  <div>Like</div>
  <div style="display: none">Liked</div>
</button>
```

And note, that selecting button / a element by `class="like-click"` is probably not what you need (it would affect all elements by that class), so better asing them ids that are unique and comes from your `{% for data in datas %}` loop

UPDATE:

Because you dont have a dislike, it could be done in same manner as in my above example:

```
<button type="button" class="button" id="btn">
  <div class="like">Like</div>
  <div style="display: none" class="like">Liked</div>
  <div class="count" id="current"> 1 </div>  
  <div style="display: none" class="count" id="clicked">  </div> 
</button>

$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#btn #clicked').html(parseInt($('#current').text()) + 1);
    $('#btn .like').toggle();
    $('#btn .count').toggle();  
})
```

Comment: Sir, since I'm pulling out the total number of Likes at the same time from database as well so it won't be that much effective. How can I do it the other way?

Comment: "Sir"? :( . In that case its better to load the initial number of likes on page load and just increment / decrement that number on click. Because every AJAX call cost quite a bit on performance

Comment: Sir, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

that's happened because you firing all button with having 'like-click' class

```
$('.like-click').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var this_ = $(this);
var quesURL = this_.attr('like-href');
$.ajax({
   url: quesURL,
   method: 'GET',
   data: {},
   success: function (data) {
    if(this_.html()=='like'){
      this_.html('liked');
    }else{
      this_.html('like'); 
    }
   }
})
});
```

Comment: Sir, this code is showing a different behavior. If I like First button only then It's updating rest of the buttons (if I click them). And If First button is not Liked then It's not updating if I click rest of the buttons first. Why so?

Comment: i was updating my answer

Comment: Sir, new answer is working fine but How can I print total number of new Likes as well ?

Comment: i think you can add news question to that. Btw please mark the answer if your problem was solved

Comment: Sure, I will. But Sir, can you please write the right way of loading the initial number of likes on page load, and just increment/decrement that number on Click along with `Like` or `Liked` button ?

Comment: First, you must set a variable to count all your of likes. Second, you can use ajax response to detecting when you must increment/decrement that variable and add it to your html element.